# jquery .remove not working

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to port a web site I wrote in php to java. And I can't figure out why my jquery isn't working in java. Here's a trimmed down function that I'm trying to get working. When I click on a button I was it to remove a div. I know my function is being called because of the alert I've put in there but the jquery is not working.

```
function divClose() 
    { 
        alert('close div'); 
        $("div.flashMessage").remove(); 

        $("div.flashMessage").fadeOut("slow", function()
        { 
            alert('close div'); 
            $("div.flashMessage").remove();
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("div.flashMessage").remove();
```

This will remove all `div`s with the class "flashMessage" from the DOM.

```
$("div.flashMessage").fadeOut("slow", function()
```

This won't be called, because `$("div.flashMessage")` will return an empty set as the `div`s were already removed from the DOM.

Comment: It wasn't a probably with the fading not working it was a problem of not removing OR fading, neither was working. So the way I was able to work around this was using $("#flashMessage").... to have jquery find it strictly by the id of the div instead of all divs with the id.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, do it in such way:

```
function divClose() 
{ 
    alert('close div'); 
    $("div.flashMessage").fadeOut("slow", function()
    { 
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Inside the `fadeOut` callback, you can just use `$(this).remove();` instead of `$("div.flashMessage").remove();`.